# TCPDF - Internal Server Error (500) on live server with large files only

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, internal-server-error

I am having an issue with TCPDF when attempting to render a large file: a 66 page HTML table, however the problem only happens after pushing the script to the live server.

My `localhost` renders the file to completion, albeit quite slowly, but the live server returns the 500 Internal Server Error eventually.

There is nothing wrong with the actual script, as far as I can tell, as reducing the size of the HTML table down to 500 rows returns the PDF in a matter of seconds.  My `localhost` takes over a minute to return the same 500 lines, and 4 minutes to return the full table, so I would have thought that the live server would make short work of it but it just cannot handle it.

Likewise, the bulk content for the PDF is generated by a script that takes over 30 seconds to render on my `localhost`, whereas the live server makes short work of it and can return the results in less than a second, so the performance of the live server is proven to be superior (as you'd expect, of course).

I've already set, to no avail:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);
```

The server is shared hosting, but I do have quite a lot of control over it and the hosting providers are willing to make reasonable changes if I can't do them myself.  However, I need to pinpoint the cause before I can ask them to make any changes.

It's not ideal, but even if the file takes a long time to complete I'm happy to implement a work-around so that the file is rendered in the background and then emails the user upon completion with a download link.  However, as the rendering aborts I can't even do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

***EDIT:***

I forgot to mention until reminded in the comments: I get nothing in the error logs.  If I remove something critical from the script, such as the DB connector, then that logs as expected, but nothing related to TCPDF is getting logged.

***Additional Info:***

I was using Dompdf originally, but this was unable to render more than 100 lines of the same table without failing.  This was both locally and on the live server, which is a shame because it handled CSS and HTML very well and required far fewer work-arounds for content positioning.

Comment: Did you check your error logs? Without that it would be just wild guessing.

Comment: @Maerlyn Sorry, I forgot to mention: no trace of any errors!  If I remove something like the database connector from the script then it fails with an error, of course, and I can see this, but nothing anywhere from after the TCPDF class is called.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and came to the conclusion that the problem was a bottleneck that forms while generating the HTML for the table and converting it to PDF format.

First I split my code into two "sections". I avoid a complex MySql query inside the loop generating the data rows by running the query externally and saving the results to a JSON file.

Then reading the JSON file I used multicell() to build my rows and columns

```
// Set MuliCell Defaults
$height = '5';
$border = '1';// 1/0 or L, T, R, B
$align = 'L';// L, C, R, J
$fill = '0'; //1/0
$Ln = '0';// 0=right, 1 = beginning of next line, 2=below
$floatX = '';
$floatY = '';
$resetH = 'true';


// Header
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'n', 15);
$pdf->MultiCell('85', $height, 'SKU', $border, $align, $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('280', $height, 'Product', $border, $align, $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Price', $border, 'R', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Pk Size', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Min', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Ord Lvl', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'On Hnd', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('70', $height, 'Counted', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
$pdf->MultiCell('32', $height, 'Var', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);

// Set DataRows
$pdf->SetXY('13', '50');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->setCellPaddings(3, 3, 3, 3);

if (!empty($json))
    {
        $rows = '0'; // Counter for rows of processed data
        foreach($json as $item) //start loop for adding
            {
                $pdf->Ln(18);// Set a new line BEFORE each datarow
                $pdf->SetX('13');                       
                $pdf->MultiCell('85', $height, $item['sku_prd'], $border, $align, $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('280', $height, substr($item['name_prd'],0,60), $border, $align, $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, $item['prefix_cur'].$item['sto_price'], $border, 'R', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, $item['sto_pack_size'], $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, $item['sto_min'], $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, $item['sto_reorder_level'], $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, $item['sto_qty_on_hand'], $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('70', $height, '', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                $pdf->MultiCell('32', $height, '', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);   
                $rows++;// increment with 1 after each datarow

                if ($rows == 27) // Set max number of datarows per page
                    {
                        $pdf->AddPage();
                        $pdf->SetXY('13', '18');

                        // Header
                        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'n', 15);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('85', $height, 'SKU', $border, $align, $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('280', $height, 'Product', $border, $align, $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Price', $border, 'R', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Pk Size', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Min', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'Ord Lvl', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('68', $height, 'On Hnd', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('70', $height, 'Counted', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);
                        $pdf->MultiCell('32', $height, 'Var', $border, 'C', $fill, $Ln, $floatX, $floatY, true);

                        // Reset font and rows to DataRows
                        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
                        $pdf->SetXY('13', '25');
                        $rows = '0';// reset to "0" ready for the new page
                    }                                   
            }
    }
```

https://www.xms-systems.co.uk/article-262-tabular-data-with-tcpdf-and-internal-server-500-error.html

Comment: It's been so long without an answer that I'd forgotten I'd asked this! 
 Interesting solution though. I considered using Multicell but did end up finding an alternative method while sticking with html, which worked and also significantly increased the speed.  I will post my solution when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @JoeP. We sure appreciate that "alternative method"...

Comment: @ner0 Are you having the same problem? The question got so little interest that I forgot it even existed. Ultimately, if memory serves, I ended up writing the table to TCPDF row-by-row, and checked the page position after each row. If it was above a particular threshold I inserted a new page, wrote new table headers, and continued writing row-by-row and repeating the page position check each time

Comment: @JoeP Thanks for the reply. It seems that you essentially implemented MultiCell as Fred suggested. The main difference seems to be that Fred uses a static row count while you check the coordinates of the page to know when it's time for a new page insert.

Comment: @ner0 True, but everything I was doing was in HTML so I had to re-declare the tbody etc each page call